# How does the echo of a radio wave from Venus depend on the rotation speed and direction of the planet?

Tags: astronomy, doppler-effect, radio-frequency

In [this paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.139.3558.910) from around 1960 scientist used echos of radio waves from the Venus' surface to determine its rotational speed and direction. How can the rotation of Venus affects the echo of the radio wave? The brief explanation is that one side of Venus is coming towards us and one side is going away and that is what causes the frequency of the echo changes. Yet, I do not understand why this is so.

Comment: The referenced article appears to be behind a paywall...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Doppler signal. The frequency of the reflected wave is changed by the reflector moving, and that shift is measured to get the velocity, usually by mixing with a wave of known frequency or by measuring a beat or phase shift.

Radio waves like acoustic wave shift in frequency when an object is moving. So, just like you hear a higher pitch as a train or an ambulance with a siren moves towards you and a lower pitch as it moves away from you.

Doppler Radar Weather station radars use the effect to measure the speed and rotation of storms.

Edit: In the paper they note that they subtract the doppler shift due to the relative motion of Earth and Venus and then look at how the remaining frequency spectrum changes. Since the period of rotation of Venus is so long 250 days they also had to play with some range gating and other tricks to understand the signal that they were getting with the experiment. The data was collected over about a 90 day time period.